# Не уникальные ID Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет! Я хочу сгенерировать не уникальные User ID для своей базы. В интернете информация и куча гайдов по уникальной User ID, но мне нужен именно повторяющейся. Можете подсказать источники, где могу почитать?

Если хотите написать определённую функцию пожалуйста пишите и все возможные варианты чтобы поменять частоту и кол-во повторений.

Большое спасибо!

Comment: а что значит "не уникальные"? почему не давать всем тогда один общий ID или вам нужен случайный ID, но который с какой-то вероятностью будет генерироваться для двух пользователей? (т.е. коллизии будут выше некоторого порога, а не ниже, как делают обычно)

Comment: вот как рекомендации все работают )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

возможно, я не совсем правильно понял вопрос, но могу предложить так:

```
import numpy as np

ids = np.random.randint(1000, 9999, 10) # генерируем 10 "случайных" чисел от 1000 до 9999
prob = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(10)) # генерируем вероятности


for i in range(5):
    print(f"Sample {i}")
    res = np.random.choice(ids, 5, p=prob)
    print(res)
```

результат (будет отличаться каждый раз):

```
Sample 0
[4569 4806 5807 8181 8181]
Sample 1
[5807 8181 4569 9526 8181]
Sample 2
[6859 5807 8181 4569 8035]
Sample 3
[6859 8181 8780 4569 8181]
Sample 4
[9426 8181 8181 8181 8181]​
```

Можете сами оценить, как повторяются некоторые числа.

Comment: `i+=1` лишнее :)

Comment: @n1tr0xs справедливо. от другого цикла осталось )

Comment: То что надо. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Простейший генератор буквенно-цифрового токена. Не уникального))

```
result = [''.join(random.choice(string.digits+string.ascii_letters) for i in range(10))]
print('result: ',result[0].lower())
```

Если убрать из кода string.ascii_letters будет генерить только циферки.
Функция range() регулирует длину последовательности.

А как тут контролировать кол-во повторений?

Напишем функцию def create_id(), которая будет принимать аргумент tries
число нужных повторений и возвращает список сгенерированых цифровых айдишников.

```
 def create_id(tries):
    array =[]
    while tries > 0:
        result = [''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(10))]
        print('result: ',result[0].lower())
        array.append(int(result[0].lower()))
        tries -=1
    return array

r = create_id(5) # передаете аргумент - число нужных повторений
print(r)
```

Comment: А как тут контролировать кол-во повторений?

Comment: Обновил свой ответ.

Comment: Я имела ввиду кол-во повторений ID 

Например create_id(5, 2, 1)

Где пять это кол-во ID, два через сколько элементов повторять и один это сколько ID повторять.

Итог: [2261714415, 3278313411, 6524026788, 2261714415, 3278313411]

Как-то так.

Comment: Понимайте таким образом я не могу контролировать кол-во повторяющейся элементов, это всё делает рандом, и в итоге повторения появляются изредко

Comment: Простите,  пока не знаю способ создания автоматически заведомо одинаковых id. Можно создать их руками, положить в список и перемешивать random.shuffle(list1).

Comment: @python_prog известно ли кол-во необходимых id в обшей сложности (кол-во пользователей) ?

Comment: @n1tr0xs около 3000

Comment: @Zhenia Kviatkivskyi Хорошо спасибо)

Comment: вот лучше чем shufle() mylist = [4847166227,9128772482,8179330765]
print(random.sample(mylist,1))